# nesting sub documents mongoose ... Is this possible

Tags: node.js, mongoose

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

I am using the above link to 'push'    children's data into parents ..

Can I push data for grandchildren  into children and into parents ?

**CODE**

```
newPatient.EmergencyContacts.push({
     emContact_Name: emContact_Name,
     emContact_Relation: emContact_Name,
})

newPatient.EmergencyContacts.emContact_Address.push({
     emContact_AddressType: emContact_AddressType,
     emContact_AddressLine1: emContact_AddressLine1,
     emContact_AddressLine2: emContact_AddressLine2,
     emContact_City: emContact_City,
     emContact_Town: emContact_Town,
     emContact_Village: emContact_Village,
     emContact_PolicStation: emContact_PolicStation,
     emContact_District: emContact_District,
     emContact_State: emContact_State,
     emContact_PinCode: emContact_PinCode
});

newPatient.EmergencyContacts.emContact_Info.push({
     emContact_phone: emContact_phone,
     emContact_email: emContact_email
});
```

**SCHEMA**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var emContactInfoSchema = new Schema({
      emContact_Phone: String,
      emContact_Email: String,
});

var emContactAddressSchema = new Schema({
      emContact_AddressType: String,
      emContact_AddressLine1: String,
      emContact_AddressLine2: String,
      emContact_City: String,
      emContact_Town: String,
      emContact_Village: String,
      emContact_PolicStation: String,
      emContact_District: String,
      emContact_State: String,
      emContact_PinCode: Number,
});


var emContactSchema = new Schema({
      emContact_Name: String,
      emContact_Relation: String,
      emContact_Address: [emContactAddressSchema],
      emContact_Info: [emContactInfoSchema],
});

var patientAddressSchema = new Schema({ 
      Patient_addressType: String,
      Patient_addressLine1: String,
      Patient_addressLine2: String,
      Patient_city: String,
      Patient_town: String,
      Patient_village: String,
      Patient_policeStation: String,
      Patient_district: String,
      Patient_state: String,
      Patient_pinCode: Number,
      Patient_countryCode: String,
});

var patientContactInfoSchema = new Schema({
      Patient_phoneType: String,
      Patient_phoneNumber: String,
      Patient_emailType: String,
      Patient_email: String,
});

var patientSchema = new Schema({
    // patient  info
    Patient_UHID: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } } , // Univesal Health Indentifier - Aadhar in our case
    Patient_altUHID: { type: String, required: false, trim: true, index: { unique: false } },  //  As per institution or vendor's specifications
    Patient_fName: String,
    Patient_mName: String,
    Patient_lName: String,
    Patient_dob: Date,
    Patient_age: Number,
    Patient_gender: String,
    Patient_occupation: String,

    Patient_Addresses : [patientAddressSchema],

    Patient_ContactInfo: [patientContactInfoSchema],

    Patient_insuranceStatus: String,
    Patient_allergyStatus: String,

    // Emergency Contact  info
    EmergencyContacts: [emContactSchema],
});

var patient = mongoose.model('patient', patientSchema);
module.exports = {
    Patient: patient
}
```

So I would like to know how it is possible.Any direction will be appreciated

Comment: Yes I tried doesnt work ....   so thats why I am asking if mongoose supports that

Comment: So how did you try, exactly? Can you show some code?

Comment: when try to POST it gives me error saying     newPatient.EmergencyContacts.emContact_Address.push({
                                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: I have declared 'EmergencyContacts' and 'emContact_Address' as arrays in the mongoose model

Comment: You should post your Schema too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible!! That's what document databases allows you to do.

As per going through to your schema , The Patient Schema has an array of emergency contacts
So `newPatient.EmergencyContacts.emContact_Address` and `newPatient.EmergencyContacts.emContact_Info` will give you error because **newPatient.EmergencyContacts** is an array.

Therefore you can't access ***emContact_Address*** and ***emContact_Info*** properties of the EmergencyContacts array that will definitely gives you **`undefined`**

Though you can access that through indexes on EmergencyContacts :

```
 newPatient.EmergencyContacts[0].emContact_Address.push({
                                            emContact_AddressType: emContact_AddressType,
                                            emContact_AddressLine1: emContact_AddressLine1,
                                            emContact_AddressLine2: emContact_AddressLine2,
                                            emContact_City: emContact_City,
                                            emContact_Town: emContact_Town,
                                            emContact_Village: emContact_Village,
                                            emContact_PolicStation: emContact_PolicStation,
                                            emContact_District: emContact_District,
                                            emContact_State: emContact_State,
                                            emContact_PinCode: emContact_PinCode
                                          });
      newPatient.EmergencyContacts[0].emContact_Info.push({
                                                emContact_phone: emContact_phone,
                                                emContact_email: emContact_email

   });
```

Hope it helps!!

> Suggestions :
> 1)Please make your question readable for other users.
>
> 2)You can refactor your schema design and please go though other
> mongoose/mongodb functions like combination of **update,$push,$elemMatch**
> etc to reduce your code length

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Would like to share.. :)

Comment: sure ... here it is ... i tried posting data to the nested array using the advanced REST client in chrome and it is working !

Comment: I will recommend you using $push through update command. It will enhance your find query capabilities as well,as you will be using $elemMatch. :)

Answer (score 0):

SCHEMA

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
       , Schema = mongoose.Schema;

```
var emContactSchema = new Schema({
                                         emContact_Name: String,
                                         emContact_Relation: String,
                                         emContact_Address: [],
                                         emContact_Info: [],
                                });




var patientAddressSchema = new Schema({               Patient_addressType: String,     
                                                      Patient_addressLine1: String,
                                          Patient_addressLine2: String,
                                    Patient_city: String,
                                    Patient_town: String,
                                    Patient_village: String,
                                    Patient_policeStation: String,
                                    Patient_district: String,
                                    Patient_state: String,
                                    Patient_pinCode: Number,
                                    Patient_countryCode: String,
                                });

var patientContactInfoSchema = new Schema({
                                        Patient_phoneType: String,
                                        Patient_phoneNumber: String,
                                        Patient_emailType: String,
                                        Patient_email: String,
                                     });

var patientSchema = new Schema({

// patient  info
Patient_UHID: { type: String, required: true,   index: { unique: true } } , // Univesal Health Indentifier - Aadhar in our case
Patient_altUHID: { type: String, required: false, trim: true, index: { unique: false } },  //  As per institution or vendor's specifications
Patient_fName: String,
Patient_mName: String,
Patient_lName: String,
Patient_dob: Date,
Patient_age: Number,
Patient_gender: String,
Patient_occupation: String,

Patient_Addresses : [patientAddressSchema],

Patient_ContactInfo: [patientContactInfoSchema],



Patient_insuranceStatus: String,
Patient_allergyStatus: String,

// Emergency Contact  info
EmergencyContacts: [emContactSchema],




});

var patient = mongoose.model('patient', patientSchema);
module.exports = {
Patient: patient}
```

CODE

```
Patient.findOne({
Patient_UHID: {
  $regex: new RegExp(Patient_UHID, "i")
}
}, function(err, doc) { // Using RegEx - search is case insensitive
if (!err && !doc) {

  var newPatient = new Patient();


  newPatient.Patient_UHID = Patient_UHID
  newPatient.Patient_altUHID = Patient_altUHID
  newPatient.Patient_fName = Patient_fName
  newPatient.Patient_mName = Patient_mName
  newPatient.Patient_lName = Patient_lName
  newPatient.Patient_dob = Patient_dob
  newPatient.Patient_age = Patient_age
  newPatient.Patient_gender = Patient_gender
  newPatient.Patient_occupation = Patient_occupation
  newPatient.Patient_Addresses.push({
                                       Patient_addressType: Patient_addressType,
                                       Patient_addressLine1: Patient_addressLine1,
                                       Patient_addressLine2: Patient_addressLine2,
                                       Patient_city: Patient_city,
                                       Patient_town: Patient_town,
                                       Patient_village: Patient_village,
                                       Patient_policeStation: Patient_policeStation,
                                       Patient_district: Patient_district,
                                       Patient_state: Patient_state,
                                       Patient_pinCode: Patient_pinCode,
                                       Patient_countryCode: Patient_countryCode
                                   });
  newPatient.Patient_ContactInfo.push({
                                        Patient_phoneType: Patient_phoneType,
                                        Patient_phoneNumber: Patient_phoneNumber,
                                        Patient_emailType: Patient_emailType,
                                        Patient_email: Patient_email
                                       });

  newPatient.Patient_insuranceStatus = Patient_insuranceStatus;
  newPatient.Patient_allergyStatus = Patient_allergyStatus;



  newPatient.EmergencyContacts.push({
                                      emContact_Name: emContact_Name,
                                      emContact_Relation: emContact_Name,
                                      emContact_Address: [{
                                        emContact_AddressType: emContact_AddressType,
                                        emContact_AddressLine1: emContact_AddressLine1,
                                        emContact_AddressLine2: emContact_AddressLine2,
                                        emContact_City: emContact_City,
                                        emContact_Town: emContact_Town, 
                                        }],
                                      emContact_Info: [{
                                                          emContact_Phone: emContact_Phone,
                                                          emContact_Email: emContact_Email,
                                                      }]


  });




  newPatient.save(function(err) {

    if (!err) {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Patient created with Patient_UHID: " + newPatient.Patient_UHID
      });
    } else {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Could not create patient. Error: " + err
      });
    }

  });

} else if (!err) {

  // User is trying to create a patient with a Patient_UHID that already exists.
  res.status(403).json({
    message: "Patient with that Patient_UHID already exists, please update instead of create or create a new patient with a different Patient_UHID."
  });

} else {
  res.status(500).json({
    message: err
  });
}
});

}
```